# Reshaping data to wide format

Tags: r, reshape

I'd like to get my data to a specific format, but don't know how to get done with reshape().

My data looks like:

```
df<-data.frame(Cues=c("A","B","C","A","B","C"), 
               Targets=rep(1:3,2), 
               Rater=rep(1:2, each=3), 
               Rating=c(1,3,5,2,4,6))
```

And I would like to get it like:

```
df2<-data.frame(Targets=rep(1:3,2), 
                Cues=c("A","B","C","A","B","C"), 
                Rater_1= c(1,2), 
                Rater_2=c(3,5), 
                Rater_3C=c(5,6))
```

I tried my best with the forum, `reshape()` and doesn't really get further. Could you guys help me?

Thanks in advance and best,
Josh

Comment: What did you try with `reshape`?

Comment: I can't make sense from your output

Comment: Me too. Please explain your output a bit more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** There is no 3C rater in the df data.frame setup, so this answer is ignoring that issue.

Bearing this in mind, one way to convert from long to wide formatted data is with the dcast function from the [reshape2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/index.html) module:

```
library(reshape2)
df2 <- dcast(df, Targets + Cues ~ Rater, value.var = "Rating")
names(df2)[names(df2) == "1"] <- "Rater_1"
names(df2)[names(df2) == "2"] <- "Rater_2"

df2
  Targets Cues Rater_1 Rater_2
1       1    A       1       2
2       2    B       3       4
3       3    C       5       6
```

Additionally, the [tidyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html) module is well worth looking at for this sort of conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was what I was searching for.. I thought I could reshape/dcast the data so that it automatically names the new columns "Rater_1" and "Rater_2". And sorry for the bad reproducible example, I tried to simplify my data and didn't do a good job. Next time, I'll be better prepared ;) Thanks for the help, makeyourownmaker!

Comment: No worries.  R is not the most straight-forward of languages!